# Using DDNS with a D-Link DIR-655 router with Dyn.com's new Updater Client Key

Tags: networking, router, dns, ddns

I have a D-Link DIR-655 router which I have set up with Dyn.com to use their DDNS server with my router as the updater client. This has worked fine with my username and password over the years.

But now dyn.com recommends creating a separate, 32-character hex key in the updater client so that you can manage your account without giving up the admin password for the account.

I created the key, and in my DIR-655's DDNS settings, I changed just the password to the key.

So it looks basically like

```
username/key: myDynUsername
password/key: *******************************
password/key: *******************************
```

Now it doesn't appear to be updating anymore. Although, there are no errors in the router's log file, and the DDNS configuration goes from Connecting to Status: Connected when I make the change.

```
username/key: *******************************
password/key: *******************************
password/key: *******************************
```

When reading the documentation on the router's limited help text, it says, if my Dynamic DNS provider gives me a Key to use, enter it in all three fields. So I did that.

It still will not update the address.

Has anybody gotten this to work?

*Details*: D-Link DIR-655 Hardware version A3, Firmware 1.33NA

Answer (score 1):

Last night I've run into the same problem as you, after "upgrading" my old Dyn account to use "Updater Client Key" because it seemed a good idea to separate access account pass from more widely used updater key.

But, surprise! The web management page of my Comtrend router only accept keys up to 16 characters in length, far less than needed for Dyn key AND THERE IS NO WAY BACK!

This is the work around that solved my problem:

1. Insert the data of the Dyn updater key in the router as "XXXXXXXX".
2. Save/export the router config data using the router web page. It is a text file.
3. Edit the config file looking for "XXXXXXXX" and replacing it with the real Dyn updater key.
4. Save the modified file.
5. Import the modified config file into the router using the router web page and reboot router.